# Fingerprint vendor missing

Tags: android, poco, build-error

**Android Build currently fails due to this missing file**

I am trying to build crDroid 12.0 using this device tree and vendor tree listed below.
https://github.com/raystef66/device_xiaomi_alioth
https://github.com/raystef66/device_xiaomi_sm8250-common
Property vendor
https://github.com/raystef66/proprietary_vendor_xiaomi

```
mdbelayet@ubuntussd:~/crDroid$ . build/envsetup.sh
ccache enabled and CCACHE_EXEC has been set to : /usr/bin/ccache
mdbelayet@ubuntussd:~/crDroid$ brunch alioth
device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:221: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:222: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
Trying dependencies-only mode on a non-existing device tree?
device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:221: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:222: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
CR_VERSION=8.1
TARGET_DEVICE=alioth
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-2a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo385
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-2a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=kryo385
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.11.0-1026-gcp-x86_64-Ubuntu-20.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SQ1A.220105.002
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=hardware/google/interfaces hardware/google/pixel device/xiaomi/sm8250-common hardware/xiaomi hardware/qcom-caf/wlan vendor/qcom/opensource/usb/etc vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common device/xiaomi/alioth vendor/xiaomi/alioth hardware/qcom-caf/sm8250 vendor/qcom/opensource/commonsys-intf/display vendor/qcom/opensource/display vendor/qcom/opensource/data-ipa-cfg-mgr vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices packages/apps/Bluetooth
device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:221: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/BoardConfigCommon.mk:222: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:196: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:197: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
CR_VERSION=8.1
TARGET_DEVICE=alioth
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-2a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo385
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-2a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=kryo385
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.11.0-1026-gcp-x86_64-Ubuntu-20.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SQ1A.220105.002
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=hardware/google/interfaces hardware/google/pixel device/xiaomi/sm8250-common hardware/xiaomi hardware/qcom-caf/wlan vendor/qcom/opensource/usb/etc vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common device/xiaomi/alioth vendor/xiaomi/alioth hardware/qcom-caf/sm8250 vendor/qcom/opensource/commonsys-intf/display vendor/qcom/opensource/display vendor/qcom/opensource/data-ipa-cfg-mgr vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices packages/apps/Bluetooth
============================================
[ 84% 214/252] test android/soong/apex                                                 0:29 test android/soong/cc                                                         0:19 test android/soong/java                                                       0:14 test android/soong/rust                                                   [ 98% 249/252] test android/soong/aidl                                                 1:13 test android/soong/apex
0:17 test android/soong/sdk
```

[100% 252/252] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"     -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used Android.bp
error: device/xiaomi/sm8250-common/biometrics/Android.bp:1:1: "android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service.xiaomi_kona" depends on undefined module "//hardware/xiaomi:vendor.xiaomi.hardware.fingerprintextension@1.0"
03:32:02 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

```
#### failed to build some targets (03:22 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

Clone your hardware tree inside '**Your DIR**/hardware/xiaomi'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31486363)